# URL is getting launch for one Test Only while trying to run the two Test In parallel

Tags: selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, testng-eclipse, testng.xml

I am trying to run two Test Methods in Parallel. Once the Test is Initiated , URL is launched on only one browser and goes blank for the Second Test. Also i observed, that if I remove 
driver manage() window() maximize();
delete Cookies Etc, then URL launches for both the Test although One Test Gets executed and another one gets failed with the error'stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document'.

Can anyone tell me how we can achieve parallel Testing ?

```
    public class CheckDepartmentsTest extends TestBase{


        public CheckDepartmentsTest() {
            super();

        }
        @BeforeMethod()
        public void setup() throws IOException {
            initialization(URL,pageLoadTimeout,implicitlyWait,ExplicitWait,Path_Current_Direc);
            Loginlogout=new LoginLogout(driver);

        }

        @Test(/*priority=3,*/enabled=true)
        public void Login_LogoutTest() throws IOException {
            Loginlogout.LoginLogoutTest(driver,action,wait);

        }

        @Test(/*priority=2,*/enabled=true)
        public void Search_Product_CheckoutTest() throws InterruptedException, IOException {


            Checkdepartments=Loginlogout.Go_To_Departments(driver,action);
            Checkdepartments.Select_Electronics_Headphones(driver,wait);
            Checkdepartments.Select_MacBook_From_SearchBox(driver,wait);

        }

        @AfterSuite()
        public void teardown() {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

    Base Class:-

    public class TestBase {

        public  WebDriver driver;
        public  Properties prop;
        public  WebDriverWait wait;
        public  Actions action;
        public String URL;
        public String path;
        public String Path_Current_Direc;
        public String currentDir = "\\QATest\\src\\main\\java\\com\\amazon\\Screenshot";
        public LoginLogout Loginlogout;
        public CheckDepartments Checkdepartments;
        public  long pageLoadTimeout;
        public  long implicitlyWait;
        public  long ExplicitWait;


        public TestBase() {
            try {
                prop= new Properties();
                FileInputStream file=new FileInputStream(TestUtil.Config_File);
                prop.load(file);
                URL=prop.getProperty("URL");
                Path_Current_Direc=System.getProperty("user.dir");
                pageLoadTimeout=15;
                implicitlyWait=10;
                ExplicitWait=8;


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    public  void initialization(String URL,long pageLoadTimeout,long implicitlyWait ,long ExplicitWait,String path_Current_Direc) throws IOException {

                if(prop.getProperty("Browser").equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",Path_Current_Direc+"\\src\\main\\java\\com\\amazon\\utility\\geckodriver.exe");
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                }
                else {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",Path_Current_Direc+"\\src\\main\\java\\com\\amazon\\utility\\chromedriver.exe");
                    driver = new ChromeDriver();
                }
                action=new Actions(driver);
                wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, ExplicitWait);
                driver.get(URL);
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(pageLoadTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(implicitlyWait, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("Thread Check  "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }

    TESTNG XML:-
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Suite" parallel="methods">
      <test thread-count="5" name="Test" parallel="methods">
        <classes>
          <class name="com.amazon.testcases.CheckDepartmentsTest"/>
        </classes>
      </test> <!-- Test -->
    </suite> <!-- Suite -->

    Expected- Both the Test Should Run in Parallel

    Actual- Only one test is getting executed as second one is getting failed
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make the WebDriver thread safe using ThreadLocal . As you are running the method in parallel its creating the problem for the Webdriver defined in TestBase . Please check below code . You should move the thread local implementation in separate class . For now modified your code as an example.

```
public class CheckDepartmentsTest extends TestBase{


    public CheckDepartmentsTest() {
        super();

    }
    @BeforeMethod()
    public void setup() throws IOException {
        initialization(URL,pageLoadTimeout,implicitlyWait,ExplicitWait,Path_Current_Direc);
        Loginlogout=new LoginLogout(TestBase.driveSafe.get());

    }

    @Test(/*priority=3,*/enabled=true)
    public void Login_LogoutTest() throws IOException {
        Loginlogout.LoginLogoutTest(TestBase.driveSafe.get(),action,wait);

    }

    @Test(/*priority=2,*/enabled=true)
    public void Search_Product_CheckoutTest() throws InterruptedException, IOException {


        Checkdepartments=Loginlogout.Go_To_Departments(TestBase.driveSafe.get(),action);
        Checkdepartments.Select_Electronics_Headphones(TestBase.driveSafe.get(),wait);
        Checkdepartments.Select_MacBook_From_SearchBox(TestBase.driveSafe.get(),wait);

    }

    @AfterSuite()
    public void teardown() {
        TestBase.driveSafe.get().quit();
    }
}

Base Class:-

public class TestBase {

   // public  WebDriver driver;
    protected static InheritableThreadLocal<WebDriver> driveSafe = new InheritableThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
    public  Properties prop;
  //  public  WebDriverWait wait;
    public  Actions action;
    public String URL;
    public String path;
    public String Path_Current_Direc;
    public String currentDir = "\\QATest\\src\\main\\java\\com\\amazon\\Screenshot";
    public LoginLogout Loginlogout;
    public CheckDepartments Checkdepartments;
    public  long pageLoadTimeout;
    public  long implicitlyWait;
    public  long ExplicitWait;


    public TestBase() {
        try {
            prop= new Properties();
            FileInputStream file=new FileInputStream(TestUtil.Config_File);
            prop.load(file);
            URL=prop.getProperty("URL");
            Path_Current_Direc=System.getProperty("user.dir");
            pageLoadTimeout=15;
            implicitlyWait=10;
            ExplicitWait=8;


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

public  void initialization(String URL,long pageLoadTimeout,long implicitlyWait ,long ExplicitWait,String path_Current_Direc) throws IOException {

            if(prop.getProperty("Browser").equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",Path_Current_Direc+"\\src\\main\\java\\com\\amazon\\utility\\geckoTestBase.driveSafe.get().exe");
                TestBase.driveSafe.set(new FirefoxDriver());
            }
            else {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",Path_Current_Direc+"\\src\\main\\java\\com\\amazon\\utility\\chromeTestBase.driveSafe.get().exe");
                TestBase.driveSafe.set(ChromeDriver());
            }
            action=new Actions(driver);
          //  wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, ExplicitWait);
            TestBase.driveSafe.get().get(URL);
            TestBase.driveSafe.get().manage().window().maximize();
            TestBase.driveSafe.get().manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(pageLoadTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            TestBase.driveSafe.get().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(implicitlyWait, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println("Thread Check  "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}

TESTNG XML:-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="methods">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test" parallel="methods">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.amazon.testcases.CheckDepartmentsTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

Expected- Both the Test Should Run in Parallel

Actual- Only one test is getting executed as second one is getting failed
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul for the great help.Have two doubts for the same, can you please address 1. What is the use of using ThreadLocal .2. When you say that implement in seperate class, what is the need to implement in seperate class as the driver initiatlization is being handled in base class only.

Comment: Threadlocal will make sure each thread gets its own copy of webdriver read http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/threadlocal.html . Moving initialization in separate class will keep driver initialization separate from test classes.

Comment: I tried to do the same, using the same logic suggested by you but this time I am getting null pointer exception at "TestBase.driveSafe.get().get(URL)" due to which Test is failing in @BeforeMethod now.

Comment: Read https://www.google.com/amp/s/rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/amp/

Comment: I read the article and tried to implement the same but still facing the same issue. Out  to browser, URL is getting launched on one Browser only.